# delete specific node from doubly linked list (in c) - can't delete tail

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to delete just one node from a doubly linked list. My function works when the node I am deleting is the list head but not if it's another node. When I test using the list tail the program never ends.

I think it has something to do with my loop and that it's not reaching the correct node or not reconnecting the list properly.

Please let me know if you have any idea or need more info. Thanks for any help you can give.

Relevant info from header:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct listNode{
        void *data;
        struct listNode *previous;
        struct listNode *next;
    } Node;

    typedef struct listHead{
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
        void (*deleteData)(void *toBeDeleted);
        int (*compare)(const void *first,const void *second);
        void (*printData)(void *toBePrinted);
    } List;

    int deleteDataFromList(List *list, void *toBeDeleted);
```

My function:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "LinkedListAPI.h"

    int deleteDataFromList(List *list, void *toBeDeleted){
        Node *temp = NULL;

        if(list == NULL || list->head == NULL || toBeDeleted == NULL) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        temp = list->head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            if(temp->data == toBeDeleted) {
              if(temp == list->head){
                 list->head = temp->next;
                 if(list->head != NULL){
                    list->head->previous = NULL;
                 }
              }
              else if(temp == list->tail){
                 if(temp->previous){
                    list->tail->previous->next = NULL;
                    list->tail = list->tail->previous;
                 }
              }
              else {
                 temp->previous->next = temp->next;
                 temp->next->previous = temp->previous;
              }

              list->deleteData(temp->data); 
              free(temp);
              temp = NULL;
              return EXIT_SUCCESS;
           }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you comparing `void` pointers? (`temp->data == toBeDeleted`) That makes no sense (unless `toBeDeleted` is actually the pointer to the node to be deleted) Where do you get `toBeDeleted` from? You need to provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Deletion from a double-libked list is usually much easier than from a single linked list. But your API provides a pointer to the data to be deleted, instead of to the node to be deleted. That is quite confusing and makes everything much more compilcated and risky. Can you change that design?

Comment: toBeDeleted is the data, the program is meant to be able to be used with any data type so the deleteData function is made data specific in a test. I can't change the API as I was assigned it.

Comment: pointers to pointers can simplfy list-handling functions.

Comment: You have: `if (temp->data == toBeDeleted) {` — surely,  you should be using `if ((*list->compare)(temp->data, toBeDeleted) == 0) {`?  That way, you're comparing values, not addresses.  If you're provided with a comparison function, you need to use it.  Sometimes, you need to use a comparison function even if you aren't provided with it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that part works fine, the head of the list deletes, it is the rest that does not